# How to align bootstrap div

Tags: php, html, css, alignment

I want to align my bootstrap div like that:

[image]

I want a container that has a border and inside it there would be those 3 div. I tried for all day, but could not figure it out using bootstrap.

My code:

```
<?php

require "navigationbar.php";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="profi.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="row" id="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 medium">
title

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 small">
description
</div>

</div>
</div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.small {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.medium {
  width: 1800px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.large {
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#row {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

The output:
[image]

In my code it does not increase the width when I try to in CSS in `.medium` and neither does it change the width for anything else. Can someone please tell me how can I do that using bootstrap (Same as the first image I drawed)?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by having one row with two columns. The first column includes two divs, the second includes the last div.

```css
#div1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#div3 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div id="div1">
      div 1
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
      div 2
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="col-4">
      div 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your design target in the first image, here's what I came up with:
[image: Result]

Hopefully it's what you were looking for. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 mainBody">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="row description">
                    <p>Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 sideBar">
                <p>Sidebar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.description {
  height: 500px;
}
```

Also, I recommend looking at the Bootstrap Grid system docs once again: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Remember, there are 12 columns and the elements need to be ordered correctly

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```